# Multiline replace in perl with extended expressions not working

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to parse the following multiline string (starting with ) and comment it out.

```
    -->
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
<!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
```

So I tried using the following:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 'BEGIN{undef $/;}
        s/
            \s+ #space at beginning of line
            (<Connector\s+ #connector
             port=\"8080\"\s+  #port
             protocol=\"HTTP\/1\.1\" #protocol
             \n  #newline
            \s+connectionTimeout=\"20000\"\n # space, connection timeout, then newline
            \s+redirectPort=\"8443\" #redirect port
            \/> # end of connector entry in file
            ) # end capture for $1
        /
            <!--$1-->
        /msx
    ' server.xml

diff server.xml server.xml.bak
```

But the diff output shows nothing.  Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: Use  something that speaks XML, not regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use that BEGIN block.  The normal way to slurp in a text file is to use the `-0` switch.  That sets the input record seperator to the null character.  If there is any chance there are nulls in the file use `-0777`.

If you know precisely what the search text is, you don't need anything as complicated as you wrote.  Perl has that use case covered.  The `\Q \E` operator automatically quotes any possibly troublesome characters but still allows variable substitution to happen.
`$foo = 'f.oo bar$'; print qr/\Q$foo\E/;`
`(?^:f\.oo\ bar\$)`

```perl
$pattern = qr{\Q<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />\E};
$text =~ s/($pattern)/<!-- $1 -->/;
```

I see that you want to do it as a command line so it would be something like this.

```
perl -i.bak -lp0e '$pattern = qr{\Q<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />\E};
s/($pattern)/<!-- $1 -->/; ' FILE
```

The code you put will only execute once because there is only "one line" to the input.

If there is wiggle room in the amount of whitespace, you can do a dynamic substitution on the pattern itself.

```perl
$pattern = qq{\Q<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />\E};
# Translate runs of escaped whitspace into a single \s+
$pattern =~ s/(?:\\\s)+/\s+/g;
$text =~ s/($pattern)/<!-- $1 -->/;
```

HTH

Comment: Don't use `-0` either. That doesn't actually do what you want. Use `-0777` (This is the same as `$/=undef;`.)  ...I note that you later mentioned how to do it right, so why did you bother mentioning the wrong way?

Comment: Why did you bother making this comment when I explicitly differentiated between -0 and -0777? :D  -0 is one of those 99% rules.  Just remember the 1%.

Comment: Re "*Why did you bother making this comment when I explicitly differentiated between -0 and -0777?*", As I said, I didn't notice the mention of -0777 when I wrote the comment

Comment: Re "*-0 is one of those 99% rules. Just remember the 1%.*", What? Why the hell would I want to use the wrong thing because it only fails 1% of the time? That's complete nonsense. And for what? To save 3 chars? How does that warrant all the confusion? Use the thing that works 100% of the time!

Comment: Re "*The \Q \E operator automatically quotes any possibly troublesome characters.*", Not quite. It doesn't quote `$`, `@` and some instances of `\ ` or prevent their effects.

Comment: Re "it's wrong".  It's not wrong.  It's TIMTOWTDI, programmer's discretion.  Perl is *postmodern*.  Not dogmatic.

Comment: You yourself said it will randomly not work. That's the very definition of wrong. TIMTOWTDI suggests tolerances to other styles. It's not talking about accepting buggy solutions.

Comment: I did *not* say it would randomly not work.  Any character that you know to not be in the file is suitable for -0.  Nulls don't happen at random.  BTW, \Q does escape $ and @.  Variable substitution happens before quotemeta is applied so it might seem to you that they are not quoted.

Comment: Re "*Variable substitution happens before quotemeta is applied so it might seem to you that they are not quoted*", That's what I said. `\Q..\E` doesn't escape `$` and `@`, but let's them have their special meaning: Interpolation.

Comment: *Not quite. It doesn't quote $, @ and some instances of \ or prevent their effects. – ikegami*

Comment: Which is true. Like you just said. `$` and `@` are still treated specially (at least some of the time) within `\Q..\E`. They still perform their interpolation contrary to what you originally said.

Comment: Re "*Any character that you know to not be in the file*", You didn't check the file, though. And it would a lot more than three character to do that!

Comment: I really don't know why you're litigating this.  *`quotemeta` does not treat $ and @ specially, ever.*  As `qq` processes the string it performs variable substitution before it interprets the `\Q` quotemeta operator. `deparse { "foo\Q .|$bar \$\Ebaz" } 9 -->  (('foo' . quotemeta(((' .|' . $bar) . ' $'))) . 'baz');`

Comment: I know why it doesn't escape certain `$`, `@` and `\ `. You didn't have to explain it to me.

Comment: `quotemeta` always escapes every $, @, and \ that it sees.  Period.

Comment: That's a straw man; I never said otherwise. I said  "it doesn't escape certain `$`, `@` and `\ `", while you incorrectly said " `\Q \E` operator automatically quotes any possibly troublesome characters". As you explained, it doesn't even see some of them, so it can't escape them. The only time `\Q..\E` works reliably is on strings interpolated within.

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured it out.

```
perl -i.bak -pe 'BEGIN{undef $/;}
        s/
            --> #preceding line ends a comment, with newline at end
            \s+ #space at beginning of line
            (<Connector\s+ #connector
             port=\"8080\"\s+  #port
             protocol=\"HTTP\/1\.1\" #protocol
            \s+connectionTimeout=\"20000\" # space, connection timeout, then newline
            \s+redirectPort=\"8443\" #redirect port
            \s+   #space
            \/> # end of connector entry in file
            ) # end capture for $1
        /
            -->\n<!-- $1 -->
        /msx
    ' server.xml

diff server.xml server.xml.bak
~
```